# Node.js - object loses values after function

Tags: node.js

I have a REST API in Node.js using Mongoose. I have the following function that does something specific for my application. The problem is that I set `test.questions` value and after a particular loop, I find it is losing scope of those variables. What is the problem here? Here is my code:

```
randomizeTest = (req, res) => {
    const test = new Test;
    let questions: String[] = [];
    let num = 5;
    while (num >= 1) {
      var self = this;
      this.quesmodel.count().exec(function (err, count) {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
        self.quesmodel.findOne().skip(random).exec(
          function (err, result) {
            questions.push(result._id);
            test.questions = questions;
            console.log(test.questions);  // prints data
          });
      });
      num--;
    }
    console.log(test.questions);  // prints nothing
    test.save(function (err, test) {
      if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(400);
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        res.status(200).json({ test });
      }
    });
}
```

After Navid's answer, I tried this now:

```
let questions: String[] = [];
let num = 5;
var self = this;
asyncLoop(questions, function (item, next) {
  while (num >= 1) {
    self.quesmodel.count().exec(function (err, count) {
      var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
      self.quesmodel.findOne().skip(random).exec(
        function (err, result) {
          questions.push(result._id);
          test.questions = questions;
          next();
        });
    });
    num--;
  }
}, function () {
  console.log(test.questions);
  console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Comment: In order to get at the root of the problem, what if you tried stripping out the inessential parts. For example, what happens if we omit any references to `this` and just write `questions.push(String(num));` in our loop? Does `console.log(test.questions);` still print nothing?

Comment: Since the operations inside while are async, second log will be executed before the aync functions finishes. By then test may or may not have results

Comment: Which database are you using?  I need to know the interface to it so I can do something different in your loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 i have mentioned the details as mongoose which means mongodb.

Comment: On stack overflow, you are not supposed to put your final code into the question.  Questions are for questions, answers are for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nodejs functions with some I/O job run asynchronously so when one thread is looping inside *while loop* and executing database I/O jobs, another one is running the rest of your code and executing `console.log(test.questions);` with its previous values which is empty.

PS. one good way to handle these type of problems is using some async libraries to run your loops sequentially like [node-async-loop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-async-loop).

```
var asyncLoop = require('node-async-loop');

var array = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2'];
asyncLoop(array, function (item, next)
{
    do.some.action(item, function (err) //database operations come here
    {
       if (err)
       {
           next(err);
           return;
       }

       next();
    });
}, function (err)
{
   if (err)
   {
       console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
       return;
   }
   // the rest of your code like console.log(test.questions); goes here
   console.log('Finished!');
});
```

this might help you but its not the best way to do it:

```
 let questions: String[] = [];
 let num = Array.from(Array(5).keys()); //this makes num = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
 var self = this;
 asyncLoop(num, function (item, next) {

    self.quesmodel.count().exec(function (err, count) {
       var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count)
       self.quesmodel.findOne().skip(random).exec(function (err, result) {
          questions.push(result._id);
          test.questions = questions;
          next();
       });
    });
}, function (err) {
  if(err)
     throw err;
  else {
     console.log(test.questions);
     console.log('Finished!');
  }
});
```

Comment: can you explain it a little more briefly with my example. I dont understand how to use the loop to my scenario

Comment: @KillerBeast Sure. First, build an array with <num> elements called array. Then you can simply use asyncLoop as shown in my answer. So each loop happens sequentially and when it's done the part where i commented (rest of your code) will happen

Comment: please check the updated question. Am i doing it right? Can never print the finished nor the data

Comment: @KillerBeast no problem. re-edit your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using the promises built into mongodb (which are a much better way to manage multiple asynchronous operations) and then simplifying things a bit with `async/await` so your loop actually runs serially:

```
randomizeTest = async (req, res) => {
    const test = new Test();
    let questions: String[] = [];
    test.questions = questions;
    try {
        for (let num = 5; num >= 1; --num) {
            let count = await this.quesmodel.count();
            let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
            let result = await this.quesmodel.findOne().skip(random).exec();
            questions.push(result._id);
        }
        console.log(test.questions);  // prints final results
        await test.save();
        res.status(200).json({ test });
    } catch(e) {
        res.sendStatus(500);
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

FYI, your scheme for picking a random record from a collection is subject to a race condition if there are other processes modifying that collection while you are selecting the random record.  This is because there's a time period between when you do `.count()` and `.skip(random)` and the collection could be changed in that time window.  There are multiple other techniques for picking a random item that each have their own situations where they are best.

Answer (score -1):

I am definitely sure this is problem with your loop. Please use async in place of while.